# Flutter - properly remove ads with in app purchases

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I am new to app-development. I am building an app with ads in it. If the user buys an in app purchase, it should not show the ads.

I saw many suggestion like adding some control variable like `bool purchased = true` and store it locally and use conditional statements to display ads or not.

Is this the only way? I am afraid storing it on sharedpref or sqlite might be risky as it can be modified by hacking.

Is there any way to query google play for in_app_purchase_status offline?

Is there any way to store it locally and verify the purchase (even in offline)?